# Mule ESB Flow calling SOAP not working but worked from SOAP UI

Tags: soap, mule, mule-studio, anypoint-studio, mule-esb

Details : I have created on flow in MuleESB which is calling a web-service without any parameter just sending it username, password and token in a property and it is working fine.

But the second API I want to post some parameters while calling soap request but I don't know how to use it I tried to pass through set payload but no response.

```
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
<http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration" host="webservicehostadd" port="443" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration">
        <http:basic-authentication username="username" password="pass"/>
    </http:request-config>
    <ws:consumer-config name="Web_Service_Consumer" wsdlLocation="https://xxxx/1.0?wsdl" service="xxx" port="xxxx" serviceAddress="https://xxxxx/1.0" connectorConfig="HTTP_Request_Configuration" doc:name="Web Service Consumer"/>
    <flow name="mycustomflow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/TEST" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <set-property propertyName="APIKey" value="xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx" doc:name="Property"/>
        <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message" metadata:id="xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxxxx">
            <dw:input-payload mimeType="application/xml"/>
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/xml
%namespace ns0 http://localhost/getDetails:getDetailsWSD
---
{
    ns0#getDetails: {
        getDetailsOrder: {
            ID: payload.ns0#getDetails.getDetailsOrder.ID,
            AllData: payload.ns0#getDetails.getDetailsOrder.AllData
        }
    }
}]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
        <ws:consumer config-ref="Web_Service_Consumer" operation="employeeDetails" doc:name="Web Service Consumer"/>
    </flow>

It showed the below error:

Exception while executing: 
[row,col]: [1,1]
Unexpected character '{' (code 123) in prolog; expected '<'
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1].
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer:

```
<dw:transform-message metadata:id="XXXXX" doc:name="Transform Message">
<dw:set-payload><![CDATA[
    %output application/xml skipNullOn="everywhere" 
    %namespace ns0 localhost/getDetails:getDetailsWSD 
    ---
    {
       ns0#getDetails: { 
          getDetailsOrder: { 
             ID: payload.ns0#getDetails.getDetailsOrder.ID, 
             AllData: payload.ns0#getDetails.getDetailsOrder.AllData 
          } 
       } 
    }]]>
</dw:set-payload>
</dw:transform-message>
```

In your scenario: you are passing a body in XML format and sometimes an empty body in your Postman requests.

Passing an empty body results your payload to be `{NullPayload}`. To handle this, we have to remove explicitly defining the input mime type: `<dw:input-payload mimeType="application/xml"/>`.

In your transformation: `ID: payload.ns0#getDetails.getDetailsOrder.ID,`. You are retrieving a value from an empty payload and this will fail. To avoid failing, we have added: `skipNullOn="everywhere"`. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/dataweave-formats#skip-null-on).

I have tried the transformation myself which results to this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ns0:getDetails xmlns:ns0="http://localhost/getDetails:getDetailsWSD">
    <getDetailsOrder/>
</ns0:getDetails>
```

I think we are done with your initial issue regarding transformation of your empty payload. Your concern now is consuming the web service.

Thank you.

Comment: I tried but it showed the below error:
And i am using POSTMAN to try this api and sending the input as params.

Exception while executing: {NullPayload} ^ Unexpected character 'N' at payload@[1:2] (line:column), expected '"'.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your Postman request? Is the body of your request empty?

Comment: yes sometimes it is empty some times error as stated above.

Comment: I see. So the parameters are optional?

Comment: Yes they are. but if they are null means no values then it is showing the result on SOAP UI as "please enter parameters"

Comment: Its very urgent to me kindly help me to solve this one!

Comment: Kindly provide the body of the request if it is not empty.

Comment: If <dw:input-payload mimeType="application/xml"/>

Then body is
    Exception while executing: 
    [row,col]: [1,1]
    Unexpected character '{' (code 123) in prolog; expected '<'
    at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1].

If <dw:input-payload mimeType="application/json"/>

    Exception while executing: 
    {NullPayload}
    ^
    Unexpected character 'N' at payload@[1:2] (line:column), expected '"'.

Comment: Try this:

        <dw:transform-message metadata:id="XXXXX" doc:name="Transform Message">
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%output application/xml skipNullOn="everywhere"
%namespace ns0 http://localhost/getDetails:getDetailsWSD
---
{
    ns0#getDetails: {
        getDetailsOrder: {
            ID: payload.ns0#getDetails.getDetailsOrder.ID,
            AllData: payload.ns0#getDetails.getDetailsOrder.AllData
        }
    }
}]]></dw:set-payload></dw:transform-message>

Comment: Its showing blank result and in mule it is showing below log:

INFO  [[checkgsbmock].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01] com.mulesoft.weave.mule.utils.MuleWeaveFactory$: MimeType was not resolved '*/*' delegating to Java.

Comment: @Mahesh_Loya Now i have a SOAP web service with ws security username password while in SOAP UI i am calling this service and adding the outgoing ws-security configuration username password add nonce and add created and applying this WS in sending the request. Response is showing but how to do from Mule CXF. 
Well i know that mule web service consumer has this option but unfortunately i don't know that bu using thew ws consumer but flow doesn't deployed it shows failed and in console shows some WSDLUtils.java error.